# Saboteur Alchemist Bore Bomb Discovery

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alchemist

I don't understand the language on the Bore Bomb discovery from the Advanced Race Guide.

The entry says "it ignores half the target's hardness and deals 1 point of damage per saboteur level" is this *in addition* to normal bomb damage, or *instead* of it?

Answer (score 5):

According to the text of Bomb(Su):

> On a direct hit, an alchemist’s bomb inflicts 1d6 points of fire damage + additional damage equal to the alchemist’s Intelligence modifier.

According to the text of Bore Bomb discovery:

> If a bore bomb strikes a wall, gate, siege engine, or similar large, solid, inanimate structure, it ignores half the target's hardness and deals 1 point of damage per saboteur level.

Now let's see what happens if a Bore Bomb strikes a wall.

1. It's a bomb, so, according to the text of Bomb(Su) it deals direct hit damage to the wall plus Alchemist's Intelligence modifier.
2. It's a bore bomb, so, according to the text of Bore Bomb discovery we have to check if it hit the wall or another solid, inanimate structure. It is true in this case. Now we reduce the hardness by half and deal one point of damage per saboteur level.
3. Let's resolve the effects now. The effects are resolved at the very same time. Damage is direct hit bomb damage, plus Int, plus one per sabouteur level minus hardness. Hardness is half of the object's hardness. Splash damage is dealt according to the normal Bomb(Su) rules.

Once again, this is not a replacement effect. Let's see some examples of replacement effects:

[Shattering](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/shattering)

> If the weapon's critical multiplier is ×3, it deals an extra 2d10 points of damage instead, and if the multiplier is ×4, it deals an extra 3d10 points instead.

[Elemental Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/elemental-spell-metamagic)

> Choose one energy type: acid, cold, electricity, or fire. You may replace a spell’s normal damage with that energy type or split the spell’s damage, so that half is of that energy type and half is of its normal type.

Discoveries, however, don't replace but agument things.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The question is whether the bore bomb is replacing the normal direct hit damage with "1 point of damage per saboteur level" or if that is in addition to the normal damage.

And why did you put the effects in that order? How can we tell, from how it's written, if the halved hardness is only applied to the damage from the Bore Bomb discovery?

Comment: Bore Bomb is a Bomb, hence all the Bomb rules apply at the last layer and all the Bore Bomb rules apply at the first layer. In game, everything resolves at the same time, so you can as well swap the layers but as a rule of thumb I prefer to bring more specific aspects to the top.

Comment: However, if you ask my subjective opinion — wording here is pretty confusing, yet unambiguous.

Comment: Right, but what place you apply halving the hardness of an object is pretty integral to the discovery. If you only halve it for the purpose of the Bore Bomb bonus damage, then it's not as effective of a Discovery.

Comment: NinthNova, effects resolve at the same time in D&D-like systems. I have updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Although per http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/damaging-objects#TOC-Hardness energy damage is halved before being applied to an object.  So it's 1/2 (bomb damage + Int) + 1/level - 1/2 hardness = damage taken.

Comment: Worth noting RAI here too.  The bore bomb is specifically intended to bust through walls and siege engines - a rather specific case.  If you *don't* go with the most generous ruling, then you're talking about comparing (saboteur level) to (half hardness) (and some stuff about reducing the target to half HP).  The discovery is available at lvl 2 - at which point the bombs are flat useless against anything over hardness 3, and (with good int) less effective than a standard bomb against the hardnesses it *can* damage.

Answer (score -3):

Bore bomb is from the advanced race guide, in the book, bore bomb has an asterisk attached (missing from d20pfsrd).

And as the Discovery description states

> Some discoveries can only be made if the alchemist has met certain prerequisites first, such as uncovering other discoveries. Discoveries that modify bombs that are marked with an asterisk (*) do not stack.

Comment: This isn't really relevant to the question - he's not asking if it stacks with other discoveries.